# Trouble with if command using grep in Terminal

Tags: regex, bash, terminal, grep

How do I do something like this?

```
"input" | \

if
grep -E 'phone_and_fax":"Phone: .*  Fax:'
then
sed 's/phone_and_fax":"Phone:/|/g' | \
sed 's/  Fax:/|/g' | \
sed 's/original_license_date":"Original License Date:/|/g'
elif
grep 'phone_and_fax":"Phone: '
then
sed 's/phone_and_fax":"Phone:/|/g' | \
sed 's/original_license_date":"Original License Date:/||/g'
elif
grep '  Fax:'
then
sed 's/phone_and_fax":"Phone:/||/g' | \
sed 's/  Fax:/|/g' | \
sed 's/original_license_date":"Original License Date:/|/g'
else
sed 's/phone_and_fax":"Phone:/||/g' | \
sed 's/original_license_date":"Original License Date:/|/g'
fi | \

"continue script"
```

The point of what is being replaced or what is being looked for doesn't really matter. What I am trying to do is use some piping to handle some text, but `if` it runs across a certain pattern using `grep` with regex, `then` it needs to change what it will replace with that particular instance. But the `grep` should not change the output of the piping.

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide an exact example of what you are trying to do, as the one in your question seems a little contrived.

Comment: grep and sed both swallow input you can't have both of them operating in a single segment of a pipeline like this.

Comment: `grep` probably isn't needed at all. If `s/is/IS/g` doesn't match the string `is`, the input is passed through unchanged, so you don't need to check if `is` is present first.

Comment: @TomFenech I fixed it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` already has `grep`-like tests built-in to its syntax:

For example, take this pseudo-code:

```
if grep -E 'some.*xt'; then sed 's/some/SOME/g'; fi
```

It can be translated into a single call to `sed`.  Observe:

```
$ echo some text | sed '/some.*xt/ s/some/SOME/g'
SOME text
```

Versus:

```
$ echo some test | sed '/some.*xt/ s/some/SOME/g'
some test
```

#### Longer example

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
if
grep -E 'some.*xt'
then
sed 's/some/SOME/g'
elif
grep 'is'
then
sed 's/is/IS/g'
fi | \
sed 's/This/""/g'
```

The equivalent `sed` statement is:

```
sed '/some.*xt/ {s/some/SOME/g; b fi}; /is/ s/is/IS/g; :fi; s/This/""/g'
```

The `elif` part of the pseudo-code is translated here to a branch statement.  If the condition `/some.*xt/` matches, then the substitution `s/some/SOME/g` is performed and `b fi` tells `sed` to jump to the label `fi`.  This does the logical equivalent of the `elif` statement.

Examples illustrate this in operation:

```
$ echo "some text This is" | sed '/some.*xt/ {s/some/SOME/g; b fi}; /is/ s/is/IS/g; :fi; s/This/""/g'
SOME text "" is
$ echo "some test This is" | sed '/some.*xt/ {s/some/SOME/g; b fi}; /is/ s/is/IS/g; :fi; s/This/""/g'
some test ThIS IS
```

Comment: This is great! I forgot to add one part to my question (I apologize for that) but what if, in the `if` command I want more than one replace to occur, but only if the value of the matched pattern is true, does this still work? or how to I run with that in the pipe command?

Comment: @double_j You can put as many replace (substitute) commands as you like after the condition by putting them in curly-braces, separated by semicolons: `sed '/some.*xt/ {s/some/SOME/g; s/text/TEXT/;}'`